# Cross Join In Sql Server not always return all rows from all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-join

Sometimes Cross join not return any rows if one of tables doesn't has any row

for example

```
WITH    q1
      AS ( SELECT   1 AS V1
           WHERE    0 <> 0
         ),
    q2
      AS ( SELECT   2 AS V2
         )
SELECT  *
FROM    q1 ,
        q2
```

I expect this query will return one row V1 = null and V2 = 2
but it returns no rows

Is there any explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cross join (cartesian product) returns every combination of rows from the two tables. i.e. each row on one table is paired with every row on the other side.

This gives `M * N` rows where `M` is the number of rows from one side and `N` the number of rows on the other.

Multiplying by zero returns zero.

If you want to preserve rows with no match on the other side you need an outer join.

```
WITH    q1
      AS ( SELECT   1 AS V1
           WHERE    0 <> 0
         ),
    q2
      AS ( SELECT   2 AS V2
         )
SELECT  *
FROM    q1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        q2 ON 1=1
```

(Or `FULL OUTER JOIN` to preserve from either side)